# BeautifulSoup does not parse content of the tag like first-name that contains '-'

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Hi i have a response like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
<first-name>hede</first-name>
<last-name>hodo</last-name>
<headline>Python Developer at hede</headline>
<site-standard-profile-request>
<url>http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=hede&amp;authType=godasd*</url>
</site-standard-profile-request>
</person>
```

And I want to parse the content returned from linkedin api.

I am using beautifulsoup like below

```
ipdb> hede = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
ipdb> hede.person.headline
<headline>Python Developer at hede</headline>
```

But when i do

```
ipdb> hede.person.first-name
*** NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: BeautifulSoup is a HTML parser, use an actual XML parser for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python attribute names can not contain a hypen.
Instead use

```
hede.person.findChild('first-name')
```

---

Also, to parse XML with BeautifulSoup, use

```
hede = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')
```

or if you have `lxml` installed,

```
hede = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```